# Thymeleaf: sec:authentication shows up at ANY case while sec:authorize at NO ANY case

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

Every `<div>` with either `sec:authentication="..."` stated shows up no matter if logged in or not. Even an explicit `false` causes the `div` to show up.

On the other side `<div>`s with `sec:authorize="..."` are hidden, even with an explicit `true`.

I have tried checking Maven dependencies, Spring MVC config, Spring Security Dialect in `ServletContextConfig` and many other answers, but no solution worked for my case.

**index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
       xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>blah blah</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">    

<div sec:authentication="true">
    authentication - always
</div>

<div sec:authentication="false">
    authentication - never
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authentication="isAnonymous()">
    authentication - anonymous
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authentication="!isAnonymous()">
    authentication - not anonymous
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authentication="isAuthenticated()">
    authentication - authenticated
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authentication="!isAuthenticated()">
    authentication - not authenticated
</div>

<div sec:authorize="true">
    authorize - always
</div>

<div sec:authorize="false">
    authorize - never
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
    authorize - anonymous
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authorize="!isAnonymous()">
    authorize - not anonymous
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    authorize - authenticated
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    authorize - not authenticated
</div>


<strong> Username: <span sec:authentication="name"></span> </strong>
<div th:text="${#authorization.getAuthentication()}">1</div>
<div th:text="${40}">1</div>




<!-- end of content! -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Expected result** (when not logged in):

> authentication - always
>
> authentication - anonymous
>
> authentication - not authenticated
>
> authorize - always
>
> authorize - anonymous
>
> authorize - not authenticated
>
> **Username: Anonymous**
>
> 40

**Actual result**:

> authentication - always
>
> authentication - never
>
> authentication - anonymous
>
> authentication - not anonymous
>
> authentication - authenticated
>
> authentication - not authenticated
>
> **Username:**
>
> 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With digging for more and more solutions I found one that fits me:

1. There must not be something like `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/");` at `SecurityConfig.configure()`.
   I.e. the page you want to apply an "authorization filter" must not be set to get ignored from security.
2. Use `sec:authorize`, not `sec:authentication` (this causes an error) in `index.html`.

Working **index.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>bla bla bla</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">

<div sec:authorize="true">
    authorize - always
</div>

<div sec:authorize="false">
    authorize - never
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
    authorize - anonymous
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authorize="!isAnonymous()">
    authorize - not anonymous
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    authorize - authenticated
</div>

<div class="container" sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    authorize - not authenticated
</div>

<strong> Username: <span sec:authentication="name"></span> </strong>
<div th:text="${#authorization.getAuthentication()}">1</div>
<div th:text="${40}">1</div>

<!-- end of content! -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result**:
(when logged in)

> authorize - always
>
> authorize - not anonymous
>
> authorize - authenticated
>
> Username: test2
>
> org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@00000000: Principal: ....
>
> 40

(when not logged in)

> authorize - always
>
> authorize - anonymous
>
> authorize - not authenticated
>
> Username: anonymousUser
>
> org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@00000000: Principal: ....
>
> 40

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using "Spring Security 5" with "thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4" caused this problem. If you're using Spring Security 5, use "thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" instead. ("thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" was released recently)